# main.c error while "making" GRASS

Tags: configuration, compiling

I use GRASS GIS 6.4.1 SVN version for my work. I keep the code in a directory inside my home directory. Today I updated it with svn up command and configured using the following command.

```
./configure --with-tcltk-includes=/usr/include/tcl8.5 --with-proj-share=/usr/share/proj --with-gdal=/usr/bin/gdal-config --with-cxx --enable-64bit --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.6-config
```

However I got one error in the make process in one d.rast module. Therefore, as instructed I changed to that directory and ran 'make' command. Now I get the following bunch of errors.

```
chethan@chethan-desktop:~/Applications/grass64_release/display/d.rast$ make
gcc -I/home/chethan/Applications/grass64_release/dist.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include  -g -O2       -DPACKAGE=\""grassmods"\"  -I/home/chethan/Applications/grass64_release/dist.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -o OBJ.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/main.o -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:89: error: ‘flag_n’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:89: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:89: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [OBJ.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/main.o] Error 1
```

I have no clue as to why these errors arise. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the code in the SVN's development branch can often be broken, you have 2 options:

1. Check out an older revision of the SVN repo: `svn checkout -r REVISION_NUMBER http://whatever/the/repo/is`, where `REVISION_NUMBER` is the last-working revision.
2. Fix it yourself - if you know C, it could be trivial.
3. Update the checked-out copy again - maybe it's already fixed!

Comment: The 3rd option helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That error means there is a problem with the source, probably they introduced a change which was not tested or is not finished. when using a version from SVN you must be prepared that it may be broken during development.